# SQL Server 2008 crash execption code 0xc0000005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crash-reports

I just observed a restart of SQL Server (Version Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6535.0) on our production server leaving the following message behind:

Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2007.100.6535.0, time stamp: 0x5531e937,Faulting module name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2007.100.6535.0, time stamp: 0x5531e937
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
Faulting process id: 0x2e7c
Faulting application start time: 01d1e5ce53c6736

Apart from that message in Windows Error Log I didn't get any hint from SQL Server error log (everything looks fine until the service is just restarting).
I looked into the SQL Server error log directory but found nothing such as a stack trace or error dump. Has this to be enabled explicitly?

Help would be greatly appreciated, where to go or what to do to get more insight into the crash than just from this error message. I haven't experienced such a situation until now.

Thanks a lot in advance

Martin

Comment: I am pretty shocked as it seems that I found the reason for this. I am using a freeware tool called data dictionary creator which opens a connection to the database using ADO.NET and a connection string. Last time I run the program sucesfully the user was a sysadmin and everything went smoothly. Meanwhile I downsized the security settings taking the sysadmin privilege away and providing just db_datareader. Now as I open the program and try to connect I get a connection error and at the same time the service restarts. For now I won't open that program again but it's quite strange and shocking.

Comment: By the way the SQL Server is run in a Windows Failover Cluster if that has something to do with the error.